# How can I print a single JPanel's contents?

Tags: java, swing, printing

I have a `JPanel` with two labels with pictures. I need to print these content of the `JPanel`. Please help me out. How can I print only this `JPanel`'s contents, as I also have different components on my `JFrame` but I just need to print **this** `JPanel`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is an example to print any Swing component.

```
public void printComponenet(Component component){
  PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
  pj.setJobName(" Print Component ");

  pj.setPrintable (new Printable() {    
    public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum){
      if (pageNum > 0){
      return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
      }

      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;
      g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
      component.paint(g2);
      return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
  });
  if (pj.printDialog() == false)
  return;

  try {
        pj.print();
  } catch (PrinterException ex) {
        // handle exception
  }
}
```

Comment: how can you scale the component accordingly in the page so that it fits?

Comment: @Saher did you ever figure out how to do this? Thanks

Comment: could you please add more explanation (text)? Is one supposed to derive a JComponent and add this method or what shall one do with this? Thank you.

Comment: [look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49378186/1273555) for a multi page printer of `Component`

Answer (score 5):

A simple way to do it would be implementing the `Printable` interface (in `java.awt.print`) and adding the specified `print` method (it works similar to `paint`—in here, you could specify what components you would want to draw onto the printed page). And when you want to actually print the contents of the panel, obtain a `PrinterJob` instance and call its `setPrintable` method, passing the object that implemented `Printable`.

That's just a quick overview, though. I'd recommend taking a look at [Sun's tutorial on printing](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/2d/printing/index.html) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

just edit and put the name of your frame, panel(jPanel1) and button(print).
'this' refers to the JFrame class(i.e my class extends javax.swing.JFrame ) just put your frame's reference instead of 'this'.

```
private void PritnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    Toolkit tkp = jPanel1.getToolkit();
    PrintJob pjp = tkp.getPrintJob(this, null, null);
    Graphics g = pjp.getGraphics();
    jPanel1.print(g);
    g.dispose();
    pjp.end();
}
```