# Adding a Print Button to JPanel

Tags: java, swing, button, printing, jpanel

I have a JPanel, with some components like buttons, labels, table, etc.

What I want to do is to add a functionality (a jButton), that clicking on that button directs me to print the whole panel, along with labels and components.
Please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750310/how-can-i-print-a-single-jpanels-contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make a JButton that calls this code:

```
public void printComponent() {

  PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
  pj.setJobName(" Print Component ");

  pj.setPrintable (new Printable() {    
    public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum) {
      if (pageNum > 0) return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;

      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;
      g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
      componenet_name.paint(g2);
      return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }
  });

  if (pj.printDialog() == false) return;

  try {
    pj.print();
  } catch (PrinterException ex) {
    // handle exception
  }
}
```

(taken from: [How can I print a single JPanel's contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750310/how-can-i-print-a-single-jpanels-contents))

Comment: hi. doesn't this code works for awt components?