# I have proplem in java i cant print all swing compont

Tags: java, swing, printing

hi everyone I'm trying to print all my swing components i find this code Could anyone explain me what does the `gettoolkit()` do? this is the code

```
Toolkit tkp = jPanel9.getToolkit();
PrintJob pjp = tkp.getPrintJob(this, null, null);
Graphics g = pjp.getGraphics();
jPanel9.print(g);
```

I can print one swing component bay calling `print()` method but not all component in the `jpanel`

Comment: you should really do a spelling check...

Comment: @NoIdeaForName Well, that stuffs me them ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `printAll` over `print`

From the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#print(java.awt.Graphics))

> public void print(Graphics g)
>
> Prints this component. Applications
>   should override this method for components that must do special
>   processing before being printed or should be printed differently than
>   they are painted. The default implementation of this method calls the
>   paint method.
>
> The origin of the graphics context, its (0, 0) coordinate point, is
>   the top-left corner of this component. The clipping region of the
>   graphics context is the bounding rectangle of this component.

And [PrintAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#print(java.awt.Graphics))...

> public void printAll(Graphics g)
>
> Prints this component **and all of its
>   subcomponents**. The origin of the graphics context, its (0, 0)
>   coordinate point, is the top-left corner of this component. The
>   clipping region of the graphics context is the bounding rectangle of
>   this component.

Possible examples...

- [Fit/Scale JComponent to page being printed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904518/fit-scale-jcomponent-to-page-being-printed/17961911#17961911)
- [Printing a JFrame and its components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764634/printing-a-jframe-and-its-components/12765916#12765916)

Comment: can you expalin me how i use it with jpanal

Comment: yourJPanel.printAll(g)...?