# How can I print a BufferedImage with Java?

Tags: java, printing

I want to print the content of I need to print the contents of a `JPanel`, that's why I keep the content as an image from `BufferedImage`. How I can print that image?a `JLabel`, and I save that in a `BufferedImage`.

Comment: Define "print"...If you're talking about printing to a printer, you can take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764634/printing-a-jframe-and-its-components/12765916#12765916) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18327234/i-have-proplem-in-java-i-cant-print-all-swing-compont/18327287#18327287) and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904518/fit-scale-jcomponent-to-page-being-printed/17961911#17961911) [and just for fun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460008/printable-prints-bufferedimage-with-incorrect-size/18466550#18466550)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

yourJPanel.getGraphics().drawImage(yourBufferedImage, 0, 0, null);