# java swing not printing complete page

Tags: java, swing, printing, awt

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.print.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;

class print  implements ActionListener,KeyListener,Printable
{
 JTable table,stable;
 JTable footer = new JTable(1,6);
 JTable table2= new JTable(11,2);;
 JPanel panel,panell;
 String data[][] = new String[100][6];
 JLabel labelf[]=new JLabel[7];
 JFrame f;
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   new print();
}
print()
{
    f = new JFrame("Bill Invoice......");
    f.setLayout(null);
    JButton jbe = new JButton("Back");
         //jbe.setFont(labfont3);

        // labfont=new Font("Kunstler Script",Font.BOLD,40);
    JLabel la1=new JLabel("SOLD TO :");
    JLabel la2=new JLabel("PROFORMA INVOICE");
    Font l1=new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,15);
    Font l2=new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,18);
    //Font l3=new Font("Times New Roman",Font.BOLD,15);
    la1.setForeground(new Color(138,10,178));
    la2.setForeground(new Color(138,10,178));

    ImageIcon ic2 = new ImageIcon("vv.jpg");
    JLabel piclab2 = new JLabel(ic2);



    JButton button = new JButton("Print");
    JButton button1 = new JButton("Save");

         JButton button2 = new JButton("Finish");
         String[] columnheader = {"S.No.", "Description", "Bales Bags", "Weight in Kgs", "Price ", "Total" };
             labelf[0]=new JLabel("txt10");
             labelf[1]=new JLabel("txt11");
             labelf[2]=new JLabel("txt111");
             labelf[3]=new JLabel("txtt");
             labelf[4]=new JLabel("txt12");
             labelf[5]=new JLabel("txtx");
             labelf[6]=new JLabel("txty");


        table2.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(200);
        table2.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);
        table2.setRowHeight(20);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("INVOICE NO.",0,0);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("txt00",0,1);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("DATE",1,0);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt(""+"currentTime",1,1);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("EXPORTRANS REF.",2,0);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("txtz",2,1);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("BOOKING NO.",3,0);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("txt22",3,1);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("CONTAINER NO.",4,0);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("txt33",4,1);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("SEAL NO.",5,0);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("txt44",5,1);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("VESSEL NAME",6,0);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("txt55",6,1);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("SHIPPING LINE",7,0);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("txt66",7,1);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("BILL OF LANDING NO.",8,0);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("txt77",8,1);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("IDF NO.",9,0);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("txt88",9,1);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("IO NO.",10,0);
        table2.getModel().setValueAt("txt99",10,1);



        table = new JTable(data,columnheader);
        //table.setTableHeader(columnNames);


        footer.getModel().setValueAt("Total",0,1);

        JTableHeader header = table.getTableHeader();
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(header, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(table, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(footer,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

         table.getTableHeader().setReorderingAllowed(false);
         table.setRowHeight(25);
         footer.setRowHeight(25);
         table.setShowGrid(false);
         table.setShowVerticalLines(true);


          JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(table);
          table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(24);
          table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(200);



         //table.getModel().setValueAt(1,0,0);


          table.getTableHeader().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(pane.getWidth(),35));

          footer.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(13);
          footer.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(190);
          footer.getColumnModel().getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(65);
          footer.getColumnModel().getColumn(3).setPreferredWidth(65);
          footer.getColumnModel().getColumn(4).setPreferredWidth(65);
          footer.getColumnModel().getColumn(5).setPreferredWidth(82);

          jbe.setBounds(0,0,105,30);
          panel.setBounds(180,350,1000,290);
          table2.setBounds(780,100,400,220);
          panel.add(pane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

          la1.setBounds(190,95,150,60);


            int y=140;
                for(int i=0;i<=6;i++)
                {
                labelf[i].setFont(l1);
                labelf[i].setBounds(190,y,500,20);
                y=y+20;
                f.add(labelf[i]);
                }
          la2.setBounds(530,300,300,60);


          button1.setBounds(1250,550,100,30);
          button.setBounds(1250,600,100,30);
          button2.setBounds(1250,650,100,30);

          table.setFont(l1);
          table2.setFont(l1);
          footer.setFont(l1);
          la1.setFont(l2);


          la2.setFont(l2);

          header.setFont(l1);
          f.add(jbe);
          f.add(la1);

          f.add(la2);
          f.add(button);
          f.add(button1);
          f.add(button2);

          button.addActionListener(this);
          button1.addActionListener(this);
          button2.addActionListener(this);
          jbe.addActionListener(this);



          f.add(panel);
          f.add(table2);

          piclab2.setBounds(0,0,1366,768);
          f.add(piclab2);

          f.setSize(1366,768);
          f.setVisible(true);

     }

 @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
    {

        String s=arg0.getActionCommand( );

        if (s.equals("Print"))
        {

                    PrinterJob pj = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

                    PageFormat pf = pj.defaultPage();
                    Paper paper = new Paper();

                    paper.setImageableArea(50, 100, 400, 200);
                    pf.setPaper(paper);

                    pj.setPrintable(this, pf);

                 if (pj.printDialog()) 
                    {
                      try 
                      {
                            pj.print();

                      } 
                      catch (PrinterException pe)
                          {
                             System.err.println("Error printing: " + pe.getMessage());
                          }

                    }
        }

    }

@Override
public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException 
{
    if (page > 0) 
    {
        return (NO_SUCH_PAGE);
    }

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;

    g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());


    Rectangle rec = f.getBounds();
    BufferedImage snapshot = new BufferedImage(rec.width,rec.height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);


    //BufferedImage snapshot = AnimeUtilities.createSnapshotOfFrame(pf, Transparency.TRANSLUCENT);
    double scaleX = pf.getWidth()/snapshot.getWidth();
    double scaleY = pf.getHeight();///snapshot.getHeight();

    double scaleValue = Math.min(scaleX, scaleY);
    System.out.println(""+scaleValue);
    g2d.scale(scaleValue+0.3, scaleValue+0.3);


    table2.print(g2d);


    return (PAGE_EXISTS);



}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

I have tried too much but this code is printing only some part of my page......i want to print whole page......I am not familier with print commands.....does anybody have idea to print whole page...

Comment: I think you need to determine area programatically, not hardcode like that `paper.setImageableArea(50, 100, 400, 200);`

Comment: what do you mean by "some part". Which part ? As @alex2410 said is that part linked to the area defined ? If yes, determine it programmatically.

Comment: @hpterm it printing only a table...not other element of class

Comment: @alex2410 plz explain what do you mean by programitically???

Comment: see next [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/750462/2894369) for printing whole component.

Comment: @alex2410 i have tryied your link but not working..Plz see my complete updated code...

Comment: You have not defined the variabls like itf2

Comment: @makky Sir i don't know itf2...can you explain little more..plz

Comment: In your code you  String txt22 = itf2.getText(); but no where you have defined the variable itf2. It won't compile.

Comment: @Makky i have changed my code..plz see...

Comment: OK I'll have a look at it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42952/discussion-between-makky-and-kuldeep-choudhary)

Comment: @Makky would you like to come on discussion.....http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42952/discussion-between-makky-and-kuldeep-choudhary

Answer (score 1):

Change your buttons `x` and `y` to make them appear on `form`

```
        button1.setBounds(100, 650, 100, 30);
        button.setBounds(200, 650, 100, 30);
        button2.setBounds(300, 650, 100, 30);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to print all the contents of the user interface. You have to make a call to the `frame.print()` method; NOT `table.print()` method.

thanks.

Comment: i tried it also...when i give frame ..then it print or table it print last row of frame only.....not complete frame...