# Printing for Java GUI using Physical Printer

Tags: java, swing

How can I print multiple Jtextfields in Java using physical printer?
I can print one jTextField using jTextfield.print()
But How to print multiple JtextFields using one print button?

Comment: See next [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/750462/2894369). It explaint how to print  `JPanel`/`JFrame`/`JComponent`.

Comment: The problem is that I want to print 8 jTextfields using a print Button. I know how to print one Jcomponent. But I don't know how to print multiple jTextfields.

Comment: add your components to `JPanel` and print it.