# How to print multiple Jtables in 1 page

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable

```
public class A
{
    public  static void Main()
    {
        JTable t1 = new jTable();
        JTable t2 = new jTable();
        t1.print();
        t2.print();
    }
}
```

I have 5  JTables which I have to print 1 after the  other on a single page. Please help me out with this

Comment: Add your tables to one `JPanel` and then read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/750462/2894369) how to print whole swing component(`JPanel` in your case).

Answer (score 0):

To print more than one JTable on a single page you cannot directly use JTable.print().
You can either put the tables in a JPanel and print the entire JPanel, or manually print the tables using this code:
http://hotcoding.crombz.com/2013/04/printing-multiple-printables-in-java.html